# Disable Luks decryption popup on startup

Tags: luks

I have an external hard drive with 20+ encrypted partitions. On each startup, this pop-up

[image: Luks Popup]

floods my screen; one for each partition. My machine has limited resources so this becomes cumbersome. I know this has to be a common problem but I cannot find a post that describes it's solution. I just want to disable the pop-ups. I don't want to remember the password forever. The partitions are decrypted via a script, when needed, and encrypted when the job is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try preventing the drive from auto-mounting on startup by following steps in this post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/638452 and updating your `/etc/fstab` file. Then have your script mount the drive on demand.

Comment: I don't want to remember forever. The partitions are decrypted via a script, when needed, and encrypted when the job is done.